# Field 'PlayerID' doesn't have a default value

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two classes, `Player` and `PlayerGoalsPrediction`.

Requests are sent in, from the frontend, containing a `playerID` and `goals` value. The `playerID` is used to find the `Player` using the `playerRepository` and then the `Player` object is used in the constructor of a `PlayerGoalsPrediction`, along with the `goals`.

However, when save the object to the db, an error (`java.sql.SQLException: Field 'PlayerID' doesn't have a default value`) is returned.

I assume it must be coming from the `PlayerGoalsPrediction.player` attribute, but that object does have a `playerID` value assigned to it, so I am unsure where the issue is coming from?

*Player.java*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Players")
public class Player {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PlayerID")
    private long playerID;
    
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(
        targetEntity=PlayerGoalsPrediction.class,
        fetch=FetchType.LAZY,
        mappedBy="player"
    )
    private List<PlayerGoalsPrediction> predictions;

    // constructors, getters and setters
}
```

*PlayerGoalsPrediction.java*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PlayerGoalsPredictions")
public class PlayerGoalsPrediction {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "PlayerGoalsPredictionID")
    private long playerGoalsPredictionID;

    @ManyToOne(
        targetEntity=Player.class,
        fetch=FetchType.EAGER
    )
    @Column(name = "PlayerID")
    private Player player;

    @Column(name = "Goals")
    private long goals;

    // constructors, getters and setters
}
```

*PlayerRepository.java*

```
@Repository
public interface PlayerRepository extends JpaRepository<Player, String>{
    
    public Player findByPlayerID(long playerID);
}
```

*PlayerGoalsPredictionController.java*

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/playergoalsprediction")
public class PlayerGoalsPredictionController {

    @Autowired
    private PlayerRepository playerRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PlayerGoalsPredictionRepository playerGoalsPredictionRepository;

    @PostMapping("/postprediction")
    public void postPredictions(
            @Valid @RequestBody PlayerGoalsPredictionRequest playerGoalsPredictionRequest 
    ) {
        PlayerGoalsPrediction playerGoalsPrediction = new PlayerGoalsPrediction(
            playerRepository.findByPlayerID(playerGoalsPredictionRequest.getPlayerID()),
            playerGoalsPredictionRequest.getGoals()
        );
        playerGoalsPredictionRepository.save(playerGoalsPrediction);
    }
}
```

Comment: As the error Message indicates, with `GenerationType.IDENTITY` JPA expects the database to take care of assigning an unique id. How this is achieved depends on your database... (i.e. column definition with auto increment)

Comment: @Turo so even though `PlayerGoalsPrediction.player.playerID` does already have an assigned value, when saving the `PlayerGoalsPrediciton` object to the db, it's not used? I am using MySQL, is a different `GenerationType` needed for `Player.playerID`?

Comment: You'd log the sql to see the failing statement, from your error message it's not absolutely clear what PlayerID field is meant, as I saw the fields exists twice...

Comment: Um, the assignment of the player is missing, at least in your shown code, from the text it should be in the cinstructor, but ....

Comment: @Turo is the line `playerRepository.findByPlayerID(playerGoalsPredictionRequest.getPlayerID())` not assigning the player when constructing the `PlayerGoalsPrediction` object?

Comment: You should check the result of the search, I think, requests can be bad!.
And show the constructor to be sure... :-)

Comment: @Turo turns out the problem was coming from a rogue `@MapsId("PlayerID")` just above `private Player player` which I had forgotten to include in the original code. Thank you very much for your help!